# a better way to manage licenses using FLEXlm?

Tags: license-key, flexlm

I have been using FLEXlm to manage all our EDA licenses through `lmgrd`. Initially, there weren't many licenses to manage so I was inclined to just fill in the SERVER and VENDOR lines with the appropriate path and port number for each license file and I just run `./lmgrd -c <license.dat>` for each license and it has been working quite well.

Recently we got to a stage where quite a few license files from various vendors need to be managed, and currently we have several processes of `lmgrd` running different daemons. The trouble is, in some cases one license from EDA vendor A is up and running, but another license file from EDA vendor B might have a different license to EDA vendor A's tool but with different features. So when I run it with `./lmgrd`, it complains about multiple daemons license server systems running.

I think there must be a better way to manage them all, but I am not sure how to do it.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Best regards,
Tidus

Answer (score 0):

Start lmgrd separately for each vendor.

lmgrd -c /vendor1/license.lic

lmgrd -c /vendor2/license.lic

After that, when you check ps-ef |grep lmgrd, you will find different process id created for each vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vivek. But that's how `lmgrd` is supposed to invoke daemon and relevant license, not the way to resolve my problem in my original post I suppose?